# How can I iteratively update a list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list where each value is a dictionary.

```
my_list = [{"key_1": "xxx", "key_2": "yyy", "key_3": None,"key_4": "www"}, {"key_1": "aaa", "key_2": "bbb", "key_3": "ccc", "key_4": "eee"}]
```

I need to remove some key value pairs from the dictionary e.g. key_2 and update a value for another key. So far I have managed to remove the keys and update the value for each dictionary, but my problem is that I can't work out how to get the updates to persist to the list.

```
for i in my_list:
    key_removal = ['key_1','key_4']
    i = {key: value for key, value in i.items() if key not in key_removal}
    if i["key_3"] is not None:
        i['key_3'] = 'ddd'
```

I have read that a for loop isn't great for doing this but as the dictionaries have the same keys it seems logical to iterate through the values of the list. Additionally the list is itself a value in a dictionary and I need the master object later. Any help would be much appreciated as I'm quite new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is nearly correct, but in your dict comprehension line you are assigning `i` to be a copy of the dict that you go through, so it is no longer pointing to the dict in `my_list`. List and dict comprehensions always return a copy. Instead I've used the `del` function to delete the key-value pairs:

```
my_list = [{"key_1": "xxx", "key_2": "yyy", "key_3": None,"key_4": "www"}, {"key_1": "aaa", "key_2": "bbb", "key_3": "ccc", "key_4": "eee"}]
for i in my_list:
    key_removal = ['key_1','key_4']
    #i = {key: value for key, value in i.items() if key not in key_removal} #<-- this line is producing new dicts, not referencing ones in my_list

    #Instead loop through the keys to remove and delete that
    for remove_key in key_removal:
        del i[remove_key]
    if i["key_3"] is not None:
        i['key_3'] = 'ddd'

print my_list
```

output:

```
[{'key_3': None, 'key_2': 'yyy'}, {'key_3': 'ddd', 'key_2': 'bbb'}]
```